# Apache Beam ReadFromText() pattern match returns no results

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm writing an Apache Beam pipeline in python and trying to load multiple text files but encounter an error when using the pattern match. When I pass in an exact filename, the pipeline runs correctly.

For example:
`files = p | 'Read' >> ReadFromText('lyrics.txt')`

However, when using pattern match an error occurs:

`files = p | 'Read' >> ReadFromText('lyrics*')`

**IOError: No files found based on the file pattern**

In this example, I have several files that start with "lyrics".

I've tried many different pattern types but haven't had any success with anything except passing the complete file name. Is there a different way to apply pattern match in this case?

**Updated with answer**

If you're on Windows don't forget to use a backslash instead of forward slash when specifying directories. For example: `ReadFromText('.\lyrics*')`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug. I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7560. In the meantime, try an absolute path or `ReadFromText('./lyrics*')`.

Comment: Thanks for filing an issue. Just a heads up, ('./lyrics*') also doesn't. Most patterns I've tried retrieve no matches.

Comment: Is this on Windows (which would require a backslash rather than forwards slash for the directory separator)?

Comment: you're correct, `ReadFromText('.\lyrics*')` worked. Thank you.